# How to change the format of the JSON output?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have PHP code which obtains data from a table in a mysql database and display that data in a JSON format.

This is my code:

```
<?php 

include ("config/config.php");
//build query
$query = 
"SELECT 
ProductID, 
Name, 
Price, 
Type,
cat 
FROM store ORDER BY ProductID ASC";

$rsPackages = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn,$query);

$arRows = array();

while ($row_rsPackages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsPackages)) {
   array_push($arRows, $row_rsPackages);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arRows);

?>
```

The output from this code looks like this:

```
 [{"ProductID":"1","Name":"HTML:Beginners guide","Price":"7.85","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"4","Name":"HTML: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"5","Name":"HTML: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"7","Name":"CSS: Beginners Guide","Price":"7.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"8","Name":"CSS: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"9","Name":"CSS: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"10","Name":"PHP: Beginners Guide","Price":"7.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"11","Name":"PHP: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"12","Name":"PHP: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"13","Name":"MYSQL- Easy steps","Price":"11.99","Type":"Book","cat":"MYSQL"},{"ProductID":"14","Name":"HTML- Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"15","Name":"CSS: Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"16","Name":"PHP: Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"22","Name":"css book","Price":"3.49","Type":"","cat":""},{"ProductID":"26","Name":"bdkjhedsjbdsasa","Price":"3.59","Type":"","cat":""}]
```

However, I want the output results to appear in a format like this:" {"records":[results] }"

example:

```
{"records":[{"ProductID":"1","Name":"HTML:Beginners guide","Price":"7.85","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"4","Name":"HTML: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"5","Name":"HTML: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"7","Name":"CSS: Beginners Guide","Price":"7.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"8","Name":"CSS: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"9","Name":"CSS: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"10","Name":"PHP: Beginners Guide","Price":"7.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"11","Name":"PHP: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"12","Name":"PHP: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"13","Name":"MYSQL- Easy steps","Price":"11.99","Type":"Book","cat":"MYSQL"},{"ProductID":"14","Name":"HTML- Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"15","Name":"CSS: Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"16","Name":"PHP: Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"22","Name":"css book","Price":"3.49","Type":"","cat":""},{"ProductID":"26","Name":"bdkjhedsjbdsasa","Price":"3.59","Type":"","cat":""}]}
```

What changes should I make to my php code to obtain the above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it up:

```
echo json_encode(array("records" => $arRows));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$result['records'] = $arRows;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse what return into a variable and add it to new json object like what i will show you now .

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"ProductID":"1","Name":"HTML:Beginners guide","Price":"7.85","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"4","Name":"HTML: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"5","Name":"HTML: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"7","Name":"CSS: Beginners Guide","Price":"7.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"8","Name":"CSS: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"9","Name":"CSS: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"10","Name":"PHP: Beginners Guide","Price":"7.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"11","Name":"PHP: Intermediate","Price":"8.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"12","Name":"PHP: Advanced","Price":"10.99","Type":"Book","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"13","Name":"MYSQL- Easy steps","Price":"11.99","Type":"Book","cat":"MYSQL"},{"ProductID":"14","Name":"HTML- Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"HTML"},{"ProductID":"15","Name":"CSS: Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"CSS"},{"ProductID":"16","Name":"PHP: Video Guide","Price":"19.99","Type":"CD","cat":"PHP"},{"ProductID":"22","Name":"css book","Price":"3.49","Type":"","cat":""},{"ProductID":"26","Name":"bdkjhedsjbdsasa","Price":"3.59","Type":"","cat":""}]');
var result = new Object();
result.result = data;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the last line of your code with

```
$data = array("records" => $arRows);
echo json_encode($data);
```